# Optionally activating a constructor in a templated class

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's suppose we have this class:

```
class MyEnumClass
{ 
public:
  enum Type
  {
    Example0,
    Count
  };
  using EnumType = Type;
};
```

And this one.

```
class MyEnumClass2
{
public:
  enum Type2
  {
    Example0,
    Count
  };
};
```

And we want to handle something related to it in a different class. But this class also supports other different than MyEnumClass classes, MyEnumClass2 is included too and have not same members. The classes are not meant to be  touched at all. So I want it to be copy constructible from its instantiable classes:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class EnumClassHandler
{
public:
  EnumClassHandler() : value(0) {}
  
  // Here want to make an optional copy constructor
  EnumClassHandler(const T::EnumType& value)
  {
    //  Do whatever
  }

  // This class should also be supported
  EnumClassHandler(const T::Type2& value)
  {
    //Do whatever
  }

  U value;
};
```

I would like this EnumClassHandler to support this:

```
typedef EnumClassHandler<MyEnumClass, uint32_t> MyEnumClassHandler;
typedef EnumClassHandler<MyEnumClass2, uint32_t> MyEnumClass2Handler;

int main()
{
  MyEnumClassHandler example = MyEnumClass::Example0;
  MyEnumClass2Handler example2 = MyEnumClass2::Example0;
}
```

Here is the [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YvIR9ybrCebeRFjC) code reflecting the problem, which is that fails on instantiating non supported constructors for different classes.

How can I make EnumClassHandler support optionally copy constructible  for those, and a bunch of similar to MyEnumClass and MyEnumClass2 classes(so modifying those internally is not allowed), in c++14?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "so I want it to be copy constructible from its base classes so:". Base class? Also the last sentence would be more clear with some examples

Comment: Please remove all the little typos from your code that it can be compiled. What is the sense of the static cast? Currently it casts form/to the same data type. Your requested function works out of the box, no idea what you want in addition. Please clarify what you want to ask! I have no idea!

Comment: You could improve the question by formulating a question

Comment: After your edit you got to times the same constructor as T::EnumType is the same as T::Type because using EnumType = Type. It makes no fun hunting behind your wrong edits. I am off... I vote to close as it is still unclear what the question is.

Comment: "*But this class also supports other different than MyEnumClass classes, MyEnumClass2 is included too and have not same members. The base classes are not meant to be touched at all.*" None of them have members, and there is no base class here.

Comment: I will check it so it is compilable, will also provide a wandbox example reflecting the issue and what I where I want to reach.

Comment: It should be ready now guys. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

To enable the constructor only for the respective `T::EnumType` or `T::Type2` you can do this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class EnumClassHandler
{
public:
  EnumClassHandler() : value(0) {}
  
  // only viable when T has T::EnumType
  template <typename W = T>
  EnumClassHandler(const typename W::EnumType& value)
  {
    //Do whatever
  }

  // only viable when T has T::Type2
  template <typename W = T>
  EnumClassHandler(const typename W::Type2& value)
  {
    //Do whatever
  }

  U value;
};
```

This will make your code work, while this

```
MyEnumClass2Handler example3 = MyEnumClass::Example0;
```

results in error:

```
<source>:56:47: error: conversion from 'MyEnumClass::Type' to non-scalar type 'MyEnumClass2Handler' {aka 'EnumClassHandler<MyEnumClass2, unsigned int>'} requested
   56 |   MyEnumClass2Handler example3 = MyEnumClass::Example0;
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vWGd6E13E).

---

PS: If possible I would rather add an `EnumType` alias to each `MyEnumClassX` to keep that complexity out of the `EnumClassHandler`. If this isnt feasible, I would use a type trait:

```
 template <typename MYENUMCLASS> 
 struct enum_type_from_myenumclass { 
     using type = typename MYENUMCLASS::EnumType;
 };
```

You can specialize it for each `MyEnumClass` that does not have the `EnumType` member alias:

```
template <>
struct enum_type_from_myenumclass<MyEnumClass2> {
     using type = typename MyEnumClass2::Type2;
};

// ... and similar for others ...
```

Then the `EnumClassHandler` only needs to use `enum_type_from_myenumclass<T>::type` and doesn't need to care about the differently named aliases.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ePnf861qb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. It is not possible to touch MyEnumClass and MyEnumClass2 classes. Sadly  there is where  I found the problem...
Let's imagine they are a black boxed number of class entities and EnumClassHandler must have a way to handle all of  them.

Comment: Omg! that was simple! I was kind of searching for a more complex way, the same as you mentioned, via type trait to make it possible without succeed. But this solution is what I was looking for. So much thanks for opening my eyes! :)

Comment: if you cannot modify `MyEnumClassX` I would go for the trait and `MyEnumHandler` then only needs a single constructor: `MyEnumHandler(const enum_type_from_myenumclass<T>::type& value)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, and as it  is the first approach I wanted. How would exactly be the type trait solution?

Comment: like in the PS. I added one example specialization

Comment: Thanks again. That is what I already tried and couldn't for some reason. Providing with a live demo will definitely help me if possible.

Comment: see edit (is too short for a comment)

Comment: Thanks a lot again.
Now I know what I was doing wrong. I was declaring the type traits structs inside the class in order to minimize namespace pollution. I will stay with  the first approach for being cleaner against that reason. 
I would give you a thousand thumbsup!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "MyEnumClassHandler example = MyEnumClass::Example0; " why is constructor not called over here, but  copy constructor is?

Comment: @CY5, here it is nicely explained:
https://newbedev.com/why-is-the-copy-constructor-called-when-we-pass-an-object-as-an-argument-by-value-to-a-method

Comment: thanks @Iñigo but the link is broken

Comment: That's odd, it still works for me.